# MVC 3 Domain Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dns, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to know if the following is possible.  I have a website called www.myweb.com.  This website could be a directory of say football teams.  The list of teams could be found here

```
www.myweb.com/home/teamlist
```

On selecting a team one would be take to

```
www.myweb.com/teams/teama or
www.myweb.com/teams/teamb etc
```

the content under the teams area would be related to them e.g.

```
www.myweb.com/teams/teama/fixtures
www.myweb.com/teams/teama/news
```

i have the above working but would like to know if it is even remotely possible to have a separate website for each team which still uses the current models, views and controllers e.g.

```
www.teama.com
```

would go to display the data from

```
www.myweb.com/teams/teama
```

where 'teams' is the controller and 'teama' is a parameter for a 'details' action. Also doing

```
www.teama.com/fixtures 
www.teama.com/news
```

would display the same stuff as

```
www.myweb.com/teams/teama/fixtures
www.myweb.com/teams/teama/news
```

many thanks and hope i have worded it ok.

Rudy

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using [IIS URL Rewriting](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/) in that case.

Comment: Thanks i would take a look.  Would have preferred to do some sort of routing, with a custom route module.  Thanks again will report back

Comment: Hmmm...had a look and am not sure this will help.  I would like the URL www.teama.com to fire a route which goes to the 'teams' controller and 'details' action with the 'id' teama.  I would like to do a routing scheme which states if the domain is www.myweb.com then carry on as normal (i.e the routes i currently have) otherwise assume it is a teams domain and do the stuff i am trying to figure out.  Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MVC Domain Routing, I'm still researching it myself as I have a similar required as yourself but I think that should do what you need.

The following links might be handy:

[ASP.Net MVC Domain Routing](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/aspnet-mvc-domain-routing.aspx)

[Bolt on multi-tenancy in ASP.Net MVC Part I (link to Part II is on the page)](http://www.agileatwork.com/bolt-on-multi-tenancy-in-asp-net-mvc-with-unity-and-nhibernate/)