# Asp.net MVC Domain Routing or Setting domain on optional MVC URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dns, asp.net-mvc-routing

How to set payed domains on optional URLs in one Asp.net MVC project like this:

- `http://domain.com/Controller/Action?id`       ----->    www.example.com
- `domain.com/Controller/Action?id2`     ----->     www.sample.net

In another words we want to map each URL to separate domain name in 1 MVC project.

It's necessary to say, that a question near this have been asked before in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107250/mvc-3-domain-routing) with some changes. And also asked before in [official asp.net site](http://forums.asp.net/t/1864602.aspx/1?Setting%20domain%20on%20optional%20MVC%20URL) by me. To clarifying the Problem, I reproduced question to achieve great answer. This question also asked from [Mr. k.Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/) before, so he suggest me to read [IRouteConstrain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988138/how-to-make-irouteconstraint-filter-route) topic in MVC.

Any way, the required configuration in Mapping routes at the Global.asax file are not bright for me.

The information that I have gathered until now are:

1. First of all, Consider we have configured required DNS options to handle requests connect to related Authoritative DNS server.
2. And now, We need to do some changes in `Global.asax` file by configuring MapRoutes.

Please Answer this question by implementing above samples.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy and external way is to use dns Redirects like bellow:

- www.example.com ----redirect to---->  www.domain.com/Controller/Action/id

can be performed at the authoritative(local) dns Server. Note that we must use possible characters in url to store in a dns RR. this can be solved changing identifiers in action or using Url Rewrite methods in IIS.
Url Rewrite allow us to have some mappings due to optimizing Urls for SEO and shortening theme like a sub domain. But, because of not using sub domains in reality, we can't have Url aliases in dns like below:

- www.domain.com/Controller/Action?id=optional ----map to --> www.domain.com/optional
- www.domain.com/optional   is not equal to   optional.domain.com
  so we can't use this aliasing:
- www.domain.com/optional  ---domain aliasing ---> www.example.com

Finally, The mapping techniques available in global.asax or C# or VB files such as Route, IRoute, etc... can be used for internal mappings and setting up MVC Routing Engine to represent different Url information but not aliasing for a domain.